# GridsearchCV doesn't check all splits

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, gridsearchcv

I have a complicated project which includes multioutput predictions and a custom scoring function (low is better).
I got a gap between the "mean-test-score" of the grid and the grade of my test set.

Turns out, the grid **checks only the first split**; on the other splits it returns 0.

On this result the grid is doing a mean score, so I got the grade of the first split divided by the number of chunks (5 in my case), and I don't get the mean of all splits.

The data:
the target is built like this - two columns of numeric continues variables, built as pandas df:

```
         a            b
0     89.993421     70.273583
1     88.089657     68.910432
2     88.412756     68.143213
3     87.360133     67.776393
4     83.236367     61.467078
```

The features - the same, 50 continues numeric columns (around 5000 rows), without nulls.

The scoring function:

```
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer


class LengthNotEqual(Exception):
    pass


def smape(observations, predictions):
    if len(observations) != len(predictions):
        raise LengthNotEqual(
            "the number of observasions and predictions don't match!")
    N = len(observations)
    return 100/N * np.sum(np.abs(observations - predictions) / ((np.abs(observations) + np.abs(predictions))/2))


def final_smape(y_true, y_predicted):
    y_true = pd.DataFrame(y_true)
    y_predicted = pd.DataFrame(y_predicted)
    final_smape = 0.25 * smape(y_true.iloc[:, 0], y_predicted.iloc[:, 0]) + \
        0.75 * smape(y_true.iloc[:, 1], y_predicted.iloc[:, 1])
    return final_smape


scorer = make_scorer(final_smape, greater_is_better=False)
```

The model code is like:

```
m = Pipeline([('std', StandardScaler()), ('dummy', DummyRegressor())])
model = GridSearchCV(estimator=m, param_grid={}, scoring=scorer, n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
display(pd.DataFrame(model.cv_results_))
display(model.best_estimator_)
print("best score:", np.abs(model.best_score_))
preds = model.predict(X_test)
print("test score:", final_smape(y_test, preds))
```

the output:
the gap between the test score to the grid score is like:

```
Pipeline(steps=[('std', StandardScaler()), ('dummy', DummyRegressor())])

best score: 1.9374532464119931
test score: 12.293068464422076
```

And in the picture (cv_results_ feature) you could see that the reason is that the grid checks only split0 and returns 0 on the other splits:

[image: cv_results]

I had the same problem in all the models I have tried.

Comment: Are you sure there is not any issue with your *data*? Run some tests with *shuffling* them first, and/or with fewer CV folds (2-3)... In any case, we will need a [mre].

Comment: i have created a random data dataframe, and it worked there. 
i think you right and there is some problem with the data even i checked that there arent nulls there , and reducing the cv number didnt worked too.
but i will check it again. thank you!

Comment: You are welcome; shuffling the data should be the very first thing to try.

Comment: i tried, didnt work, but when i find something i would update the question. thank you very much @desertnaut

Answer (score 2):

I have found the problem:
it was that my scorer has mixed dtypes and functions of numpy and pandas.

converting all to numpy solved the problem.

```
y_test = y_test.to_numpy()
y_train = y_train.to_numpy()

def smape(y_true, y_pred):
    error = np.abs(y_true - y_pred)
    scale = (np.abs(y_true) + np.abs(y_pred)) / 2
    return np.mean(error / scale)


def final_smape(y_true, y_pred):
    rougher = smape(y_true[0], y_pred[0])
    final = smape(y_true[1], y_pred[1])
    return 0.25 * rougher + 0.75 * final

from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer
scorer = make_scorer(final_smape, greater_is_better=False)
```